# How-to deploy a JavaFX application as debian package with IntelliJ IDE

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea, javafx, deployment, deb

I could only find information of using Netbeans to package a JavaFX app into .deb, but I couldn't find any info on how to do this with IntelliJ.

I am using Gradle as the build tool.

Could you guys share some insight?

Comment: Consider using Maven, see this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50590738/how-to-set-the-install-path-on-a-self-contained-app-javafx-deb-debian-package

Comment: You may try going to Project Structure | Artifacts, add there JavaFX app, in JavaFX tab define "deb" native bundle and build artifacts with Build -> Build Artifacts. Does it work for you?

Comment: @OlgaKlisho Thanks Olga, this really helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as Olga pointed out, her advice helped me:

> in Project Structure | Artifacts, add there JavaFX app, in JavaFX tab
>   define "deb" native bundle and build artifacts with Build -> Build
>   Artifacts